maven-war-plugin will not generate MANIFEST file
I have an older project that has a manually defined MANIFEST.MF file checked in that I'm trying to delete and autogenerate instead.
Maven makes it sound like this should be a simple task, but it hasn't panned out that way for me. After making the changes below, running a mvn clean install will not generate a manifest file at all, and the generated WEB-INF only contains build.properties.
The project has 4 poms total. Below is the basic structure, with the children in the build order defined by the parent <modules>.
app-parent (pom) 
 - app-common (jar)
 - app-web (war)
 - app (ear)

Original app-web POM
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>WebContent/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

Updated app-web POM
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

^ I got rid of <pluginManagement> b/c it seemed unnecessary. This didn't break things while I was still using the <manifestFile> config, so I doubt it matters to the answer.*
Ear POM  (Unchanged)
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <earSourceDirectory>${basedir}</earSourceDirectory>
                <earSourceExcludes>META-INF/ibmconfig/**/*,target/</earSourceExcludes>
                <modules>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>app-common</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>app-common.jar</bundleFileName>
                    </jarModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>app-web</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>app-web.war</bundleFileName>
                        <contextRoot>app-web</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

